# How to terminate AWS managed blockchain instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-managed-blockchain

I followed these instructions below to get an AWS Ethereum instance running, however since I am just learning blockchain, I would like to create an image and start/stop as needed. However when I go to EC2 and stop my instance, it restarts. I saw other posts about this being caused by elastic beanstalk but when I go to elastic beanstalk, I don't see anything there. What else could be causing it to restart?
Thanks!

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/blockchain-templates/latest/developerguide/blockchain-templates-getting-started.html

Comment: Do you have an Auto Scaling Groups? Check.

Comment: No, both AWS Auto Scaling and Elastic Beanstalk have nothing.

Comment: Although when I go to CloudFormation > Stacks.. one of the stacks description says "This template creates an AutoScalingGroup of EC2 Instances"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the **source code** of one of its nested stacks [ethereum-autoscalegroup.template.yaml](https://aws-blockchain-templates-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/ethereum/templates/latest/templates/ethereum-autoscalegroup.template.yaml), you can see that it actually creates **instances in an autoscaling group** (ASG).

Instances in ASG **can't be stopped**. However, you can terminate them, by setting [desired capacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-manual-scaling.html) and `minimum capacity` to 0 of your ASG. Then if you want to create new instances when you need them, you can change desired capacity back to 1.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was looking under AWS Auto Scaling > Scaling plans when I should have looked under EC2 > Auto Scaling groups